# How do i Reverse output already piped from sort and cut commands

Tags: shell-script, grep, sort, cut

I have to take user input of there UID then use it to reference the /etc/passwd directory and sort the data by first name and display only username,firstname,lastname in that order. The problem i'm having is sorting the output. if i use a command like

```
cat /etc/passwd |grep  $id_prefix | sort | cut -d: -f1,5
```

The output sorts by username and displays in a lastname, firstname order. I know I could
change the command to something like.

```
cat /etc/passwd |grep  $id_prefix | sort | cut -d: -f5 | sed 's/\([^ ]*\)[ ][ ]*\([^ ]*\)/\2 \1/'
```

Then I will get the output sorted and cut how I want it but it will not contain FIELD1, the usernames. How would I write this to correctly display all the fields I need and also sort them?

Comment: It would be easier if you could show some sample of input, and desire output.

Comment: The input would be a user id prefix, for instance all users in my class have the same first 5 letters for a user id and the rest is unique. so my input would be for example ClassA and this is where I am using grep because it will ignore any users from other classes. ClassB, ClassC ect. The output should show ( UserID , FirstName, LastName,)

Comment: please create a minimal sample of your input file and add it to your question. It is hard to understand what you are trying to do from above description.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
awk -F: '{ print $1"   "$5 }' /etc/passwd | sort -k2
```

This will parse the username and comment fields from `/etc/passwd` and `sort` on the second field which will be the first name of the user, provided they are listed in first name and last name order.

Here is an example of incorporating `grep`:

```
grep "500\|501\|502" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print $1"    "$5 }' | sort -k2

jira    Atlassian JIRA
dick    Richard Jameson
bob    Robert Gillespie
```

**EDIT:**

Use this to reverse the lastname, firstname ordering from the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
awk -F: '{ print $1"   "$5 }' /etc/passwd | awk '{ print $1"    "$3" "$2 }' | sort -k2
```

The above example modified for lastname, firstname in the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
grep "500\|501\|502" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print $1"    "$5 }' |  awk '{ print $1"    "$3" "$2 }' | sort -k2
```

This works if there are not, and should not be, any commas separating first/last, last/first names.

**EDIT (the second):**

Since the last/first names are comma separated, this should work:

```
awk -F: /$id_prefix/'{ print $1"    "$5 }' /etc/passwd | awk -F, '{ print $1"    "$2 }' | awk '{ print $1"    "$3"    "$2 }' | sort -k2
```

Thank you @Jidder for recommending not piping from `grep` to `awk`.

Comment: They are sorted by LastName, FirstName, in the /etc/passwd file which is what I am having trouble with because essential I have to reverse the middle field and last field of my output

Comment: The /etc/passwd file actually does use a comma as a delimiter between lastName FirstName. I am not that familiar with awk in general but if I used a , instead of the space between $1 and $5 would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it:

```
grep mohsen /etc/passwd | awk -F':' {'split($5,a,",");printf "username is :%s ,uid is: %s , name is %s \n",$1,$3,a[1]  '}
```

Output is:

```
username is :mohsen ,uid is: 1000 , name is Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh
```

Comment: This keeps returning an unterminated string error I couldn't find where it was though.

Comment: please replace your username with mohsen.I got answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get away with something like this:

```
grep $id_prefix /etc/passwd | cut --delimiter: --fields=1,5 | sort --field-separator=: --key=2
```

You could also add `--ignore-case` option to `sort` if needed in your context. Check [its docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sort-invocation) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why people are piping grep into awk.
You could do it all in awk.
This presumes that first and last name are separated by a space.
Where USERNAME is the search term

```
awk -F: '/USERNAME/{split($5,a," ");print $1,a[2],a[1]}' etc/passwd
```